# ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars bug

Tags: python, pytorch

I am making dataloaders of a dataset of 10560 images, of them 1000 are for test, and the bigger part is divided into train and val in 85:15 ratio.
Batchsize is 100
The code is:

```
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, samples, transform = None):
        self.transform = transform
        self.samples = samples

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        s1, s2, t = self.samples[index]
        s1 = imread(os.path.join(current_path, string, s1))
        s2 = imread(os.path.join(current_path, string, s2))
        s1 = gray2rgb(s1)
        s2 = gray2rgb(s2)

        if self.transform:
            s1 = self.transform(s1)
            s2 = self.transform(s2)

        t = torch.tensor(t)
        return (s1, s2, t)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.samples)


train_dataset = CustomDataset(trainlist, transform=transform)
test_dataset = CustomDataset(testlist, transform=transform)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, drop_last=False)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, num_workers=4, drop_last=False)
```

And I am just trying

```
for e, (inputs1, inputs2, labels) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
    print(e)
```

to test the code. But I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

I must say, before this, I was working with a similar but smaller dataset and the code was same. There I wasn’t getting this error.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried making num_workers in the dataloader 0 or 1? Or making your # images/batches  % num_workers == 0?

Comment: yes I tried numworkers = 0

Comment: and I also tried images % num_workers == 0

Comment: Hmm if you also get the error without transforms I am out of ideas. Good luck.

Comment: Can you give more detail on where the error arises from? Do some quick tests to determine whether it happens in `__getitem__`, or, quite likely `collate`

Comment: @DerekG its on __getitem__

Comment: which sub-function? Also, looks like we may need to see the details on `gray2rbg`

Comment: from skimage.io import imread and from skimage.color import gray2rgb

Comment: As I said, all worked for a similar dataset. it was a smaller one. it also worked for a bigger one